# Excute dos command in perl

Tags: perl, cgi, dos

I have a simple perl script in cgi file to find and replace a text in dos such as:

```
system("type data.txt | powershell -Command "$input | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace \"ID\", \"$id\" }" > new.txt");
```

or

```
system("cat tmp/$id/index.html 's/ID/$id/g' a");
```

(I have Powershell and Cygwin)

When I run this script, nothing happen!
But if I directly type this command in cmd (windows), It's done!
And my question is: how to run these commands in my CGI file?

Comment: The command `copy tmp/$id/index.html 's/ID/$id/g' a` looks like bogus.  Probably you meant to write something like `copy tmp/$id/index.html \`echo "$a" | sed 's/ID/$id/g'\``?  Anyway, the substitution is easy to make in Perl; why do you want the system to do it for you?

Comment: Sr, it is 'cat', not 'copy'. $id to get a dynamic parameter in my program.

Comment: I don't understand why this command can run directly in cmd but when I run CGI file written by Perl, it can't excute

Comment: Why are you using powershell from perl? You have Perl.

Answer (score 1):

```
open(my $fh, "<", "data.txt") or die "Error opening data.txt: $!";
open(my $out, ">", "new.txt") or die "Error opening new.txt: $!";
my $id = 'NewId';
while (<$fh>) {
    s/ID/$id/g;
    print $out $_;
}
close $fh;
close $out;
```

Answer (score 0):

Typically this happens due to the environment not being set the same for your shell and your perl environment.  It's usually fixed by using explicit path names to your commands.

So rather than

```
system("cat tmp/$id/index.html 's/ID/$id/g' a");
```

Try

```
system("/bin/cat tmp/$id/index.html 's/ID/$id/g' a");
```

which would work on my machine.  From cygwin, you should be able to figure out what the path of any given command by typing in `which command`, replacing `command` with the command you need to find the path of.

I'm not as familiar with Powershell as I am with Cygwin, also, I don't know if you are using a Cygwin perl.  Odds are that you'll have to use a unix style path to get at your commands; if you are using cygwin, you can use something that will look like `/cygdrive/c/window32/powershellcommand.exe`.  If not, you'll have to look for the documentation for your version of perl to get the exact syntax (or someone else will have to correct me).

Hope that helps!

Comment: I tried
system("/bin/cat tmp/$id/index.html 's/ID/$id/g' a");
But it's same as first.
I don't know how to confige the path of any given command in cygwin.
I edit this file from a source written for unix system and I want to run it on IIS of windows. These command make me confused :(
Thank you for ur helps